# CakePHP3: can't get localisation working

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization, cakephp-3.4

According to the [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/fr/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html), I prepared my localisation files:

```
/src
    /Locale
        /...
        /es_ES
            default.po
```

my `default.po` contains something like

```
msgid "Oui"
msgstr "Sí"

msgid "Non"
msgstr "Non"

msgid "Continuer"
msgstr "Continuar"
```

I of course use `__("...")` in my view.

I added `I18n::locale('es_ES');` in my controller.

But the view is still in default language.

What do I miss please?

And How to get the language selected by:

```
// inconfig/bootstrap.php
DispatcherFactory::add('LocaleSelector');

// Limite locales to en_US and fr_FR only
DispatcherFactory::add('LocaleSelector', ['locales' => ['en_US', 'fr_FR']]);
```

**EDIT**
I suppose that I now have to write the following code in 3.4:

```
class Application extends BaseApplication
{
    /**
     * Setup the middleware your application will use.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue $middleware The middleware queue to setup.
     * @return \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue The updated middleware.
     */
    public function middleware($middleware)
    {
        $middleware
        // Catch any exceptions in the lower layers,
        // and make an error page/response
        ->add(ErrorHandlerMiddleware::class)
        // Handle plugin/theme assets like CakePHP normally does.
        ->add(AssetMiddleware::class)
        // Apply routing
        ->add(RoutingMiddleware::class)
        ->add(new LocaleSelectorMiddleware(['de', 'fr','en', 'es', 'it', 'nl'])); // I added this to the skeleton
        return $middleware;
    }
}
```

I also modified `webroot/index.php`

Comment: Start with clearing the cache (`tmp/cache/persistent`). Also you may want to elaborate on the specific technical problem you have with "_getting the language selected by_" the locale selector filter. ps, dispatcher filters are deprecated as of 3.4, you should use **[middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html)** instead.

Comment: @ndm Thanks for your answer. so I delete `tmp/cache/persistent` and I have the same problem. As I use `I18n::locale('es_ES');` to test, I think I'm not concerned by a potential DispatcherFactory problem. Anyway, it's in the 3.4 doc. Not sure to understand what to do with the middleware. Can you check my edit?

Comment: @ndm so we now have to remove lines such as `DispatcherFactory::add('Asset');` in `bootstrap.php`?

Comment: Why did you modify `webroot/index.php`? Did you check what `debug(\Cake\I18n\I18n::locale())` outputs?

Comment: @Mary Possibly to enable the middleware stack.

Comment: If clearing the cache doesn't help, then you'll have to do some debugging... as Mary suggested, check if the locale is set properly (right before you use the translation function), also check the cache to figure whether your translation files are being recognized/parsed/stored correctly (should be something like `myapp_cake_core_translations_default_es__e_s`).

Comment: @ndm Didn’t realize he was apparently upgrading from a older version.

Comment: @Mary Well I can't really tell for sure, I'm just connecting the dots and shooting in the dark - might as well have just killed some coyotes :)

Comment: @Mary, yes I upgraded to older version and [so...](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#adding-http-stack)

Comment: @Mary @ndm, thanks for `debug(\Cake\I18n\I18n::locale())` but it really tells me `es_ES` as expected. I can see a `secondguide_cake_core_translations_default_es__e_s` file in `tmp/cache/persistent` but the page is still in french very strange. Maybe it doesn't find the translation for any reason. How to find why?

Comment: Are there any `*.mo` files beside your `*.po` files? If so you should regenerate them, because the will take precedence over `*.po` files from experience. If this is not the case, you should dig deeper. Maybe throw some `debug()`’s into the core’s `LocaleSelectorMiddleware` methods to see what’s going on there – only temporarily for sure.

Comment: Did you add `es_ES` to the valid `$locales` of `LocaleSelectorMiddleware`?

Comment: @Mary, no I first did it [like that](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#automatically-choosing-the-locale-based-on-request-data) but it seems it's a deprecated method. How to do it with the middleware? I didn't find it.

Comment: @Mary, and I don't have any `mo` files.

Comment: Check the API. You obviously just pass an array of allowed locales to the middleware. https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.I18n.Middleware.LocaleSelectorMiddleware.html

Comment: @Mary @ndm, so I added the missing locale in `LocaleSelectorMiddleware` instanciation and checked it with a `debug()` in the middleware code. But same...

Comment: @Mary, @ndm, in fact that partially works. it works on very simple sentences such as `Oui`, `Non` but maybe I have a problem as soon as the `msgid` i.e. the default sentence can contain `'` (curly quote). I extracted messages with `cake i18n extract` and it doesn't escape any character. Is there some limitation in `msgid` content. I didn't see anything like that [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html)

Comment: Holy moly! If it works "partially", it is definitely no problem with the Middleware etc. Make sure **all** messages are extracted by the Console (no manual copy & paste inserting) and use PoEdit or some similar application to translate.

Comment: @Mary, I found, this because my po files where not stored in UTF-8.

Comment: Great. I recommend PoEdit since it reduces the risk of formatting pitfalls like this for you.

Comment: @Mary, yeah, thanks a lot